# Link Probability prediction between two nodes using Machine Learning or Deep Learning where node to node mapping is given

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

Can someone please direct me to a tutorial provide a starting idea for the problem given below.

I have a mapping of Authors to co authors given as follows:

```
mapping
>>
{0: [2860, 3117],
 1: [318, 1610, 1776, 1865, 2283, 2507, 3076, 3108, 3182, 3357, 3675, 4040],
 2: [164, 413, 1448, 1650, 3119, 3238],
} # this is just sample


link_attributes.iloc[:5,:7]
>>

first   id  keyword_0   keyword_10  keyword_13  keyword_15  keyword_2
0        4      0        1.0             1.0    1.0         1.0
1        9      1        1.0             1.0    1.0         1.0
2        7      2        1.0             NaN    1.0         1.0
3        6      3        1.0             1.0    NaN         1.0
4        9      4        1.0             1.0    1.0         1.0
```

**I have to predict the probability of having a link between a `Source` and `Sink`**

For example if I am given a `Source`=13 and `Sink`=31 then I have to find the probability of having a link between 13 and 31. All the links are un-directed.

Comment: Could you send me whole the dataset. I wanna play with it before give you a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, this a private dataset. Can't povide you.  Could you please help me? with an initial idea or tutorial on anything at all?

Comment: Ok, let me try with some code after a coffee.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to give you the data. I'll have to check for some things. Do you have any experience in this field of Link prediction? This is my first time in this kind of Problem.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field. Currently, I'm an ungraduate student learning in Computer Vision field. But I still want to try with ML problems. I think I will start with Fully Connection Neuron network with 10 layer, loss function will be cross entropy. Of course, it's just starting point and I need adjust the model more to improve prediction performance.

Comment: But what is the idea to build a model? one we have is  id-id mapping, other we have is attributes for each id which have lot of ```NaN```. Can you please tell me how could I start looking at the problem?

Comment: The model will be Fully connected neuron net with input shape = (2 * number of features), the output will be scalar in range (0,1) by using Sigmoid as activation function for the last layer. First, I would consider Nan as a value of 0. For better performance, we need a technique called Feature Selection.

Comment: Where are the class Y-labels? We have features for every id but how will you find the probability of a id-id link using NN?

Comment: @TaQuangTu I am actually missing the starting the idea. How should I go and tackle this problem.

Comment: is link attributes information about two different sources that have a link, or you have that information for every source ? if you only have information for linked sources, it would be hard to train any machine learning model

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen I have attributes for Each and Every Node and a mapping of source node to destination. I do not know how to create the X attributes and y_labels. I mean I am clueless about the situation how could I use these attributes for a start.

Comment: sure, as bounty is finishing I need to post an answer, I will construct a solution and will update as I complete it

Answer (score 5):

```
import json
import numpy
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

def get_keys(data, keys):  # get all keys from json file
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            get_keys(item, keys)
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        sub_keys = data.keys()
        for sub_key in sub_keys:
            keys.append(sub_key)

# get all keys, each key is a feature of instances
json_data = open("nodes.json")  # read 4016 instances
jdata = json.load(json_data)
keys = []
get_keys(jdata, keys)
keys = set(keys)
print(set(keys))

def build_instance(json_object):  # use to build instance from json object, ex: instance = [f0,f1,f2,f3,....f404]
    features = []
    features.append(json_object.get('id'))
    for key in keys:
        value = json_object.get(key)
        if value is None:
            value = 0
        elif key == 'id':
            continue
        features.append(value)
    return features

# read all instances and format them, each instance will be [f0,f1, f2,...], as i read from json file, each instance will have 405 features
instances = []
num_of_instances = 0
for item in jdata:
    features = build_instance(item)
    instances.append(features)
    num_of_instances = num_of_instances + 1
    print(num_of_instances)

# read "author_id - co author ids" file
traintxt = open('train.txt', 'r')
lines = traintxt.readlines()

au_vs_co_auth_list = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.split('\t', 200)
    print(line)
    # convert value from string to int
    string = line[0]  # example line[0] = '14 445'
    id_vs_coauthor = string.split(" ", 200)
    id = id_vs_coauthor[0]
    co_author = id_vs_coauthor[1]

    line[0:1] = [int(id), int(co_author)]
    for i in range(2, len(line)):
        line[i] = int(line[i])
    au_vs_co_auth_list.append(line)

print(len(au_vs_co_auth_list))  # we have 4016 authors

X_train = []
Y_train = []
generated_train_pairs = []
train_num = 30000  # choose 30000 random training instances
for i in range(train_num):
    print(i)
    index1 = numpy.random.randint(0, len(au_vs_co_auth_list), 1)[0]
    co_authors_of_index1 = au_vs_co_auth_list[index1]
    author_id_of_index_1 = au_vs_co_auth_list[index1][0]

    if index1 % 2 == 0:  # try to create a sample that two author is not related
        index2 = numpy.random.randint(0, len(au_vs_co_auth_list), 1)[0]
        author_id_of_index_2 = au_vs_co_auth_list[index2][0]

        # make sure id1 != id2 and auth 1 and auth2 are not related
        while (index1 == index2) or (author_id_of_index_2 in co_authors_of_index1):
            index2 = numpy.random.randint(0, len(au_vs_co_auth_list), 1)[0]
            author_id_of_index_2 = au_vs_co_auth_list[index2][0]
        y = [0, 1]  # [relative=FALSE,non-related = TRUE]
    else:  # try to create a sample that two author is related
        author_id_of_index_2 = numpy.random.randint(1, len(co_authors_of_index1),size=1)[0]
        y = [1, 0]  # [relative=TRUE,non-related = FALSE]

    x = instances[author_id_of_index_1][1:] + instances[author_id_of_index_2][
                                              1:]  # x = [feature1, feature2,...feature404',feature1', feature2',...feature404']
    X_train.append(x)
    Y_train.append(y)
X_train = numpy.asarray(X_train)
Y_train = numpy.asarray(Y_train)
print(X_train.shape)
print(Y_train.shape)

# now we have x_train, y_train, build model right now
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=X_train[0].shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=512, epochs=3, verbose=2)
model.save("model.h5")
# now to predict probability of linking between two author ids

id1 = 11  # just random
id2 = 732  # just random

author1 = None
author2 = None
for item in jdata:
    if item.get('id') == id1:
        author1 = build_instance(item)
    if item.get('id') == id2:
        author2 = build_instance(item)
    if author1 is not None and author2 is not None:
        break

x_test = author1[1:] + author2[1:]
x_test = numpy.expand_dims(numpy.asarray(x_test), axis=0)
probability = model.predict(x_test)

print("author id ", id1, " and author id ", id2, end=" ")
if probability[0][1] > probability[0][0]:
    print("Not related")
else:
    print("Related")
print(probability)
```

Output:

```
author id  11  and author id  732 related
```

Comment: I think there should be ```set(keys)``` in ```for key in keys:```  in ```build_instance()``` method. No? Else it will keep  copying the values.

Comment: @Deshwal The method is trying to reconstruct an instance of a particular instance in Json file by copying json values.

Comment: I think there is an error in ```X_train,y_train``` separation in line ```co_authors_of_index1 = au_vs_co_auth_list[index1]``` when you re run the code, it shows  ```List index out of range```

Comment: @Deshwal it's my mistake, there are 4016 instance in au_vs_co_auth_list. So, random index must in range (0,4016), not (0,4080)

Comment: Because of the more than 100000 values per instance, it is blowing the 16 GB memoy. It is supposed to run only on Kaggle. But at th X_train,y_train split, it is blowing off the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Before diving into how to find a solution, I recommend understand your data well, and spend a good part of your time digesting the problem and preparing a dataset.

So from the scenario you described it seems to me your problem is **given two Nodes and their attributes predict if there is a link** this can interpreted as a binary classification task. I will provide an initial minimalistic simple solution.

what confused me is that you mentioned you have only `link_attributes.iloc[:5,:7]` link_attributes but not node attributes. In the case you have node attributes it makes more sense because then we just make a combinations of pairs of nodes, and label the pairs wich are not connected as `0 or not_connected` and the ones connected as `1 or connected`.

So let's make a dataset. As I'm didn't exactly understand what the link attributes mean, let's generate some random data but we can adapt a better example if you edit your question with more details about your data.

***About creating a Dataset***
For every nodes in the mapping we will create 10 dummy random columns just for the sake of demonstrating.

Then we will create a list of all authors and coauthor called `list_of_authors` and generate pairs out of this calling it `pair_of_authors`.

for every `pair of authors` we will label them as linked or not linked using `mapping`, for that I created a function called `check_if_pair_is_linked`.

after this I will show how to create a simple baseline solution for the task. We will use scikit-learn with has a [big list](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) of easy to use models for classification.

***Code***

I folded the code and describe it in 3 major simple steps:

1. prepare your inputs to create a dataset (using mappings and attributes)
2. create dataset (for every pair of authors, label then as linked or not and concatenate their attributes)
3. Use sci-kit learn to fit, predict and evaluate a a model

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn import svm

######## first preparing data to create a dataset
+-- 17 lines: ### we already have mappings {---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This part creates -----> mappings => {
                                      0:[coauthor12,coauthor17231,...],
                                      1:[...],
                                        ...,
                                      732: [...]
                                      }
i                        author_attributes => {
                                               0:[a0_1,attr0_2,...,attr0_10],
                                               1:[a1_1,attr1_2,...,attr1_10],
                                               ...,
                                               732: [...]
                                              }

#### Generating our Dataset and preparing dataset to the scikit-learn library(and most other) format
### The idea is generating pairs of authors regardless if they're linked or not and label if a pair is linked
+-- 24 lines: {--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This part creates, a list of pairs of authors containing (attributes_of_both_authors, is_linked_label)
-----> dataset  = [
                     ([a0_1,...,a0_10,a1_1,...,a1_10],label_pair0_1)),
                     ([a0_1,...,a0_10,a2_1,...,a2_10],label_pair1_2),
                                ...

                 ([a142_1,...,a142_10,a37_1,...,a37_10],label_pair142_37),
                  ]

#### Training and evaluating a simple machine learning solution
+-- 12 lines: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------This part outputs a report about the model after training the model with a training dataset and evaluate the model in a test dataset (I used the same train data and test data but dont ever do that in a real scenario)
----->         precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.93      1.00      0.96       466
           1       1.00      0.10      0.18        40
```

***Solution***:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn import svm

######## first preparing data to create a dataset
#### we already have mappings
def generate_random_author_attributes(mapping):
    author_attributes = {}
    for author in mapping.keys():
        author_attributes[author] = np.random.random(10).tolist()
    for coauthors in mapping.values():
        for coauthor in coauthors:
            if author_attributes.get(coauthor, False): 
                pass # check if this coauthor was alredy added
            else:
                author_attributes[coauthor] = np.random.random(10).tolist()
    return author_attributes 
mapping = {
 0: [2860, 3117],
 1: [318, 1610, 1776, 1865, 2283, 2507, 3076, 3108, 3182, 3357, 3675, 4040],
 2: [164, 413, 1448, 1650, 3119, 3238],
}
#### hopefully you have attributes like this, for each author you have some attributes, I created 10 random values for each for demonstrating
author_attributes = generate_random_author_attributes(mapping)

#### Generating our Dataset and preparing dataset to the scikit-learn library(and most other) format
### The idea is generating pairs of authors regardless if they're linked or not and label if a pair is linked
def check_if_pair_is_linked(pair_of_authors, mapping):
    ''' return 1 if linked, 0 if not linked'''
    coauthors_of_author0 = mapping.get(pair_of_authors[0],[])
    coauthors_of_author1 = mapping.get(pair_of_authors[1],[])
    if(pair_of_authors[1] in coauthors_of_author0) or (pair_of_authors[0] in coauthors_of_author1):      
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def create_dataset(author_attributes, mapping):
    list_of_all_authors = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([coauthors for coauthors in mapping.values()]))
    list_of_all_authors.extend(mapping.keys())
    dataset = []
    for pair_of_authors in itertools.permutations(list_of_all_authors, 2):
        pair_label = check_if_pair_is_linked(pair_of_authors, mapping)
        pair_attributes = author_attributes[pair_of_authors[0]] + author_attributes[pair_of_authors[1]]
        dataset.append((pair_attributes,pair_label))
    return dataset

dataset=create_dataset(author_attributes, mapping)
X_train = [pair_attributes for pair_attributes,_ in  dataset]
y_train = [pair_label for _,pair_label in  dataset]

#### Training and evaluating a simple machine learning solution
binary_classifier = svm.SVC()
binary_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)


#### Checking if the model is good
X_test = X_train # never use you train data as test data
y_test = y_train
true_pairs_label = y_test
predicted_pairs_label =  binary_classifier.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(true_pairs_label, predicted_pairs_label))
```

***OUTPUT***

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.93      1.00      0.96       466
           1       1.00      0.15      0.26        40

    accuracy                           0.93       506
   macro avg       0.97      0.57      0.61       506
weighted avg       0.94      0.93      0.91       506
```

Comment: Sorry. These were Node attributes actually. I might have done it unknowingly

Comment: I have 2 files. One with the correct mapping as you have described ```mapping {1:[2,3,4,5]}``` and the second one with something that has ```x_attributes``` for a node like ```place of birth, age, education``` etc etc for all the nodes in the data.

Comment: great, so this solution fits your needs ? I don't know why the  green correct solution sign disappeared from my answer

Comment: I'll have to check it. Sorry no offence. Anyways it looks promising than the first one.

Comment: Actually I am quite unable to relate this to my data. I mean it confusing I could I fit my data into your scenario as you have generated random numbers and so on. Is there a way I could provide my dataset to work with?

Comment: sure, maybe you could put a sample of the data in the question ? you should change the random data with your actual author attributes. a dictionary {author_id : list_of_attributes} but list of attributes need to be numeric in order to work in the machine learning model

Comment: so if you have text featues or categorical features you have to transform them

Comment: Oh. Okay so the random numbers you have put here represent each row if I am not wrong ? where each each is a node attribute?

Comment: yes... if by row you mean an author/node then yes. and we have one list of attributes per author/node

Comment: I tested your idea. It is same as checking 0/1 for each node. I'e tried it already.Problem? ```(4016*450)``` when converted into 0/1 mapping for each node, blows the memory out of proportion. Kaggle is unable to handle.

Comment: could you send the link for the dataset ?  the dataset created is telling if a pair of authors is linked (checking if the edges of the nodes is 0/1 if each node is an author)... (4016*450) shouldn't be a problem in memory, it's not too big but I can take a look anyways